# Fetching Solr parameters from the component entry in the solrconfig file

Tags: java, solr

I'm writing a custom Solr component. This is how I currently fetch a Solr parameter in the component code:

```
SolrParams params = rb.req.getParams();
int paramValue = params.getInt(PARAM_NAME, 0);
```

The above code assigns the integer value of the parameter `PARAM_NAME` to the `paramValue` variable. The `getInt` method tries fetching the value from a GET parameter named `PARAM_NAME` sent to Solr via HTTP. If there's no such a GET parameter it fetches it from the `defaults` entry of the request handler entry in `solrconfig.xml`.

My custom component will be used in several request handlers. Most of the component parameters are common to most of the request handlers. I don't want to configure the common parameters inside each and every such request handler. I have tried defining the common parameters in the `defaults` entry of the component entry. Unfortunately, the `params.getInt` method doesn't try fetching parameters from the component's `defaults` entry, but only from the request handler's `defaults` entry.

I need a method that tries fetching a parameter from the component's `defaults` entry before trying fetching it from the request handler's `defaults` entry.